# npm install --save react-google-recaptcha is failed when use in the app

Tags: react-native, recaptcha

I am trying to use the google recaptcha in my app. I have install it using `npm install --save react-google-recaptcha`. When i import it to my app and save the project.It gives me following error.

import

```
import ReCaptcha from 'react-google-recaptcha'
```

error

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "D:\\My Work\\Company Projects\\Ongoing\\ZappyFoods\\Mobile App\\zappyfood_app\\node_modules\\react-google-recaptcha"
```

how can i solve this isssue

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015